# Laravel API with routes returning 404 not found with nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I made a simple API to use a SDK, it receives two parameters, do some checks and return a new value, It's very simple.

When I try locally with PHP artisan serve, I works nice, I can make the request with a http client.

But when I upload it to my linux vps and configure with nginx, it won't work, I searched a lot, tried a lot of settings with params and args on tried files, but the problem persists, can anyone give me a hint?

This is my api.php

```
Route::get('/ali/{url}/{type}', [AliexpressController::class, 'index']);
```

This is my vhost

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name aliapi localhost;
    root /var/www/alilinkgen/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include conf/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have setted my hosts to 172.0.0.1 aliapi

Can anyone give me a hint about it?

Edit:

After the comments I changed my vhost, and it was working with two parameters, I changed the code and now I need only one parameter, now it's giving error 404 again.

This is my API route

```
Route::get('/ali/{url}', [AliexpressController::class, 'index']);
```

This is my vhost

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name aliapi;

    index index.php;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.log;

    root /var/www/alilinkgen/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-Real-IP "$remote_user";
    #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;

    # RFC 6797
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    # Disallow Wireshark/XSS Hijacking Back To Unsecure
    add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure";

    # Remove info disclosure
    server_tokens off;

    #set_real_ip_from  172.18.0.0/24;
    #real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    # SWEET32 - TLSv1.2 defualt enabled
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
       #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       gzip_static on;
    }

   location = /favicon.ico {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
   }

   error_page 404 /index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include conf/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /healthz {
        stub_status;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a dockerized environment for laravel, you can check the [configuration for nginx](https://github.com/Kyle-Jeynes/Laravel-Dockerized/blob/main/laravel/nginx.conf) I used and just update it to suit your local instance (ie, the fastcgi_pass needs changing to your local socket). Alternativley, spin it up using Docker ;)

Comment: You're listening on port 5000? Why not listen on port 80? Check out that Dockerized environment, that nginx.conf file is a good example

Comment: yes, I did it on port 5000, this API will be not public, I just need that a bot I created using nodejs access the data from the API, I got the script from the github provided on the first comment and changed some parameters, it seens that worked now, but I don´t know what was the problem and what fixed, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I changed my project and now the route need only one parameter, now it's giving 404 again :(